# problem in summation of numbers between 1 to N in python

Tags: python

When I try to calculate the summation of numbers between 1 to N number with python I tried this code

```
N = int(input())
S = int(N*(N+1)/2)
print(S)
```

It works well until i tried to input N=641009859 the expected result should be= 205446819988104870
but the result is= 205446819988104864

What is the wrong in here?

Comment: Use `//` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`N * (N + 1) / 2` does float division, and floating point numbers can't all be exactly represented. Do integer division: `N * (N + 1) // 2` gives you what you expect (`205446819988104870`)

Additional reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](//docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Alternatively, you could bit-shift to the right by one bit (`N >> 1`), which is the same as dividing by two because of how the [binary system works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_two#Binary).

`(N >> 1) * (N + 1)` gives the same answer as before.